# Github pages not redirecting after updating A records

Tags: dns, github-pages

I used to host my website firstnamelastname.com using JustHost for 3 years. I was not interested in renewing, so I let it delete itself. I own the domain using bigrock and removed the previous nameservers (ns[1-3].justhost.com), and added the two A records that github pages mentioned.

Despite that, my website, when searched for, just shows an empty webpage with justhost.com. What am I missing? Should I add anything else? (did not add CNAME records coz they are mutually exclusive, right?)

Also, added an uppercase CNAME file to the root of the repo. The settings on the repo do mention that the site is being published at http://firstnamelastname.com.

And lastly, it's been 5 hours.

```
;; global options: +cmd
;firstnamelastname.com.     IN  A
com.            5   IN  SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1409603760 1800 900 604800 86400
```

^This is what I get when I do "dig firstnamelastname.com +nostats +nocmd +nocomments". And the url gives "webpage not found" error. So I am assuming I may have gotten something wrong with the A record?

Comment: Have you read through the Pages help doc ("[Tips for configuring an A record with your DNS provider](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider)") on this? If so, and you really think you have everything setup correctly, you could always try [emailing GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that A records are :

```
@ 10800 IN A 192.30.252.153
@ 10800 IN A 192.30.252.154
```

That your CNAME file is at the root of your **user/organisation master branch** or **project gh-pages branch** with content :

```
firstnamelastname.com
```

And wait at least 48 hours. DNS propagation can take this long !

But it's easier to give an answer with real url to dig.

Comment: Sorry, what is the 10800? I only see an option to specify domain (which I do as the top level, no www), then the IP, and then TTL. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I emailed github but they said that something is wrong with the DNS provider. I haven't gotten around to emailing those guys yet :(